# llenar varios combobox por medio de un metodo vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

quiero llenar varios combo box que tengo en un formulario de vba excel, pero no quiero escribir la rutina varias veces, la idea es enviar la info a un metodo y que este sea el que me llene los combo box,

el metodo que tengo es este:

```
Sub FillinCombobox(table As String, couple As String)
   Dim products As Variant
   productData = oProducts.Misc(table, couple)
   For Each Product In productData
     cbCategory.AddItem Product
Next Product
```

End Sub

La idea es poderle eviar el control al metodo para que pueda agregar la info en cada uno de los combo box que tengo en mi formulario.

agradezco mucho la ayuda prestada

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes?¿Qué error te da? ¿Qué esperar conseguir? ¿Qué input tienes?¿Qué output buscas? Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Supongamos que deseas llenar datos desde una **tabla Excel** .Puedes hacer los siguiente para todos tus combobox. Ejemplo: `cbCategory.list = ListObjects("nombreDeTabla").listColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value`. Eso te cargará de forma automatica todos los valores de una tabla y de la primera columna. Si tienes una duda puedes a clararlo en tu pregunta.